# Will disabling logging in Cygwin console improve performance and memory usage?

Tags: performance, cygwin

I have Apache Solr running on Cygwin.
Currently all requests are logged to the Cygwin console.

If I disable this logging, will it improve performance and allocated memory?

And if so: where can I disable logging?

Comment: If you want to run a full web application in cygwin, I think you are better off having a virtualbox running ubuntu server. You will save yourself much headache that way.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying :) Is a virtualbox something that I can run on my existing Windows VPS? Sort of a virtual machine? And why would it save me much headache? What are the pros and cons of using your solution?